# Displaying LINQ query in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I'm having trouble displaying this LINQ query in a dataGridview:

```
var result = from myrow in MydataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         where liste.Any(x => myrow.Field<string>("ID").ToUpper().Contains(x.ToUpper()))
                         select myrow;
MyGrigdView.DataSource = result.Tolist();
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the gridview needs some way of getting access to the information about what columns there are for it to effectively bind the data.  If it has an object with properties for each column it can work, but you don't have that.  If the entire collection implements a given interface that explains what columns there are and how to get them, then it can work.  `DataTable` implements such an interface, `IEnumerable<DataRow>` does not.  The simplest option here is likely to put all of those rows back into a `DataTable` so that the binding can function.  Just replace `ToList` with `CopyToDataTable` (you may need to add a relevant `using`).